# Save multidemnsional array as userdefaults in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array that I can't seem to save as a user default with Swift.

```
var shoppingLists = [
    (name: "Giant", items: ["Salad", "Bread"]),
    (name: "ShopRite", items: ["Chips", "Dip"])
]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(shoppingLists, forKey: "GroceryList");
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Any Idea what I could be doing wrong? If I have a simple array such as var list = [1,2,3,4] I can save it fine. But I can't seem to save is how it is currently structured.

Comment: Don't use NSUserDefaults. Instead serialise the array with NsKeyedArchiver.

Comment: Tuples, they should not be used in data structures, from the Apple iBook Swift: “Tuples are useful for **temporary** groups of related values. They are not suited to the creation of complex data structures. If your data structure is likely to persist beyond a temporary scope, model it as a class or structure, rather than as a tuple.” Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2 Prerelease).” [iBooks](https://itun.es/us/k5SW7.l)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't a multidimensional array. This is an array of tuples. Tuples do not conform to `NSCoding`, so you can't put them into NSUserDefaults.

You should replace your tuples with a simple class that implements `NSCoding`. Then you can use `NSKeyedArchiver` to serialize it into `NSUserDefaults`. See [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE) for details.

Alternately, you could encode this as an Array of Dictionaries:

```
var shoppingLists = [
    ["name": "Giant", "items": ["Salad", "Bread"]],
    ["name": "ShopRite", "items": ["Chips", "Dip"]]
]
```

This isn't bad for storage, but I wouldn't work with the data this way. It's almost always better to create an actual model type rather than rely on tuples or dictionaries.

(Side note: there is almost never a reason to call `synchronize()`. It just pauses your program. It doesn't actually cause anything to be written.)